# Android Studio - Please change caller according to com.intellij.openapi.project.IndexNotReadyException documentation

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile, android-gradle-plugin

i started getting this error that's preventing me from building my project

```
3:11:08 PM Gradle sync started
3:11:12 PM Gradle sync completed
3:11:13 PM Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]
3:12:51 PM Please change caller according to com.intellij.openapi.project.IndexNotReadyException documentation: Please change caller according to com.intellij.openapi.project.IndexNotReadyException documentation
3:12:53 PM Please change caller according to com.intellij.openapi.project.IndexNotReadyException documentation: Please change caller according to com.intellij.openapi.project.IndexNotReadyException documentation
3:12:54 PM Please change caller according to com.intellij.openapi.project.IndexNotReadyException documentation: Please change caller according to com.intellij.openapi.project.IndexNotReadyException documentation
3:12:56 PM Please change caller according to com.intellij.openapi.project.IndexNotReadyException documentation: Please change caller according to com.intellij.openapi.project.IndexNotReadyException documentation
3:13:31 PM Gradle build finished in 2m 19s 29ms
```

in the event log. I've looked at other issues... invalidate caches/restart doesn't do anything nor does adding

```
android {
aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false
}
```

in my build.gradle.
I looked at some other resources that said this error could be tied to bad image files? I added a .png recently but i already tried closing AS > deleting the picture > re-adding it to drawable > start AS > clean project. but that doesn't seem to help either.

if anyone has any other ideas or solved this before i would greatly appreciate it....this has been holding me back from progressing for a while now. thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and just as in your case none of the mentioned solutions worked.

My issue was that I miss-clicked when I tried to associate a value declared in strings.xml to an **android:text** field of a TextView. This miss-click resulted in the string being associated to *android:tools*.

The result was the same: IndexNotReadyException.

Once I removed the android:tools from xml the error disappeared. What confuses me the most is the fact that I could build and deploy app on my phone even though android:tools doesn't really exist (at least not in the TextView context).

I suggest anyone having this error to check the latest changes to UI and double-check associated .xmls. The error isn't always highlighted in red letters, sometimes you have to hover the mouse over it in order for the text "Unkown attribute:..." to appear.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and the solution was to remove elaviation and shadows from elements.